# Eslint isn't checking .ts or .tsx files

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

When I run `yarn lint` or `eslint` directly, it's not checking my `.ts` or `.tsx` files at all.

Have tried fiddling with various configuration options. I've installed the appropriate plugins and parsers.

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "eslint", "eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "plugin:import/typescript"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "jsx-a11y", "import", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 7,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [
      "error",
      120,
      2,
      {
        "ignoreUrls": true,
        "ignoreStrings": true,
        "ignoreComments": true,
        "ignoreTrailingComments": true,
        "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "import/extensions": ["error", "never", { "packages": "always" }],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["warn", { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {},
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    },
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    }   
  }
}
```

If I pass `--ext "ts,tsx"` to eslint, the errors I get are completely off (it seems to be treating the files like JS files).

I have VSCode and VSCode seems to be linting all my files correctly (js as JS, ts and tsx as Typescript).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `yarn run eslint src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}` where `src` is the directory you want to lint

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this

```
 "overrides": [
{
  "files": ["*.tsx", "*.ts"]
}]
```

in your .eslintrc config file